# Cómo extraer datos a través de una tabla que solo contiene los id de mas tablas?

Tags: sql, join, postgresql-9.3

He creado la tabla *"propuesta"*, la cual sólo contiene como campos los id's de las demás tablas, el detalle es que tengo que extraer datos como (`nombre_docente`, `nombre_materia`, `nombre_dia`, `hora`, `grado`, `grupo`) de las demás tablas a través de mi tabla *"propuesta"*, la cual contiene el id de cada tabla.
No encuentro la manera de hacerlo, espero puedan ayudarme. saludos.

Les dejo a continuación la tabla `propuesta`:

```
 id_propuesta | id_docente | id_materia | id_dia | id_hora | id_grado | id_grupo
--------------+------------+------------+--------+---------+----------+----------
```

Comment: debes agregar el nombre de las otras tablas, y esos ID que dices son llaves foraneas, puedes hacer acceso a sus tablas a traves de inner join

Comment: deberias poner mas informacion sobre de que tablas probienen las *id*, supongo que esas son llaves foraneas, con excepccion de *id_propuesta*. pero en si utiliza lo que es inner join para relacionar las tablas cuyas id estan involucradas. la informacion que proporcionas es implicita

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que vincular las tablas donde están los nombres, quedaría algo así:

```
SELECT P.id_propuesta, P.nombre_propuesta, D.id_docente, D.nombre_docente,
   M.id_materia, M.nombre_materia,
   Di.id_dia, DI.nombre_dia,
   G.id_grado, G.nombre_grado
FROM propuesta P
INNER JOIN docente D on D.id_docente = P.id_docente
INNER JOIN materia M on M.id_materia = P.id_materia
INNER JOIN dia    DI on DI.id_dia = P.id_dia
INNER JOIN grado  G on G.id_grado = P.id_grado
```